# Erro no Edit MVC .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

estou com um erro quando vou editar meu cadastro, meu Model Fisica está como `PartialView`,o seguinte erro ocorre:

```
Attaching an entity of type 'Projeto.Models.Fisica' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value
```

**MODEL CADASTRO**

```
public class Cadastro
{
    public Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; } 
    public Fisica Fisica { get; set; }
}
```

**MODEL FISICA**

```
    public class Fisica : Pessoa
    {
        public string RG { get; set; }
    }
```

**MODEL PESSOA**

```
    public partial class Pessoa
    {
      [Key]
      public int IdPessoa { get; set; }
      public string Nome { get; set; }
    }
```

**VIEW EDIT**

```
    @model CodeFirst.Models.Cadastro
    <div>
       @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Fisica)
    </div>
```

**PARTIAL VIEW FISICA**

```
                    @model CodeFirst.Models.Fisica
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-1-5 marginCimaBaixo">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RG)
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RG)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RG)
                    </div>
```

**CONTROLLER EDIT POST**

```
    public ActionResult Edit(Cadastro cadastro)
    {
       db.Entry(cadastro.Fisica).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Agora você fez certo a herança. Vou responder.

Comment: Dear lord, quase mil pontos e ainda não sabe que "obrigado" aqui se faz com +1? Isso é ruído meu caro, Furlan, tá lá no 1º guia que a gente deve ler quando começa a usar este site: [tour] ---> ***`não tem bla bla bla`***. Obrigado pela compreensão!

Answer (score 6):

Se `Fisica` deriva `Pessoa`, isto aqui não está certo:

```
@model CodeFirst.Models.Fisica
<div>
   @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Fisica)
</div>
```

Use `@Html.Partial` ao invés de `@Html.Editor`:

```
@model CodeFirst.Models.Fisica

<div>
   @Html.Partial("_MinhaPartialPessoaFisica", Model)
</div>
```

E a `Partial`:

```
@Model CodeFirst.Models.Fisica

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-1-5 marginCimaBaixo">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RG)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RG)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RG)
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Fisica fisica)
{
   db.Entry(fisica).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

---

Isto aqui está terrivelmente errado, e mostra que você não entendeu como herança funciona:

```
public class Cadastro
{
    public Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; } 
    public Fisica Fisica { get; set; }
}
```

Se `Fisica` deriva `Pessoa`, você não precisa ter `Fisica` e `Pessoa`. Aliás, você não precisa nem ter essa *ViewModel* `Cadastro` porque como `Fisica` já deriva `Pessoa`, todos os campos de `Pessoa` já existem em `Fisica`.

Portanto, sua *View* `Edit` deve ficar assim:

```
@model CodeFirst.Models.Fisica
<div>
   @Html.Partial("_MinhaPartialPessoaFisica", Model)
</div>
```

Comment: esqueci de mecionar na pergunta umas coisas, vou editar

Comment: olhe novamente por favor

Comment: Já estou desistindo de te responder. Sério mesmo.